# How do I handle printf in a nested for Loops construct in C?

Tags: c, for-loop, printf, nested-loops

I need to implement a function using nested for loops in C.

The function has the following declaration:

```
void nest_loop(int n);
```

and should print the following for the value n = 5

```
A B C D E
  A B C D
    A B C
      A B
        A
```

However I need to implement the function so it produces output for any unsigned int n from the following Intervall [0,9]

In the case of n = 5

From my understanding there are 5 for loops.

for_loop1  prints 5 times the char 'A'

for_loop2  prints 4 times the char 'B'

for_loop3  prints 3 times the char 'C'

for_loop4  prints 2 times the char 'D'

for_loop5  prints 1 time the char 'E'

Also from my understanding the nested loop construct should look something like this:

```
int n = 5;
int c = n - 1;

for(int i = c ; i < 0; i--){ // loop for 'E'
  c--;
  for(int j = c; j < 0; j--){ // loop for 'D'
    c--;
   for(int k = c; k < 0; k--){ // loop for 'C'
     c--;
    for(int l = c; l < 0; l--){ // loop for 'B'
      c--;
     for(int p = c; p < 0; p--){ // loop for 'A'
     }
    }
   }
  }
}
```

Is my nested for loop construct correct? 
If yes, then how do I now implement printf to produce the output mentioned?

Comment: *"However I need to implement the function so it produces output for any unsigned int n from the following Intervall [0,9]"* what if the number entered isn't `5`? Then what will your 5 nested loops do?

Comment: You need only two `for` loops: one that prints each character in a line, and one that is responsible for printing a line.

Comment: If the problem is to print a 2D pattern, then your problem has 2 dimensions. This means 2 loops. Take a pen and determine row and column indices (starting from zero), this will make it easier to understand how to print a letter at `(row, column)`, or `(i, j)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the functional code.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void nest_loop(int n) {
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            printf("  ");
        char init_char = 'A';
        for(int j = 0; j < n-i; j++, init_char++)
            printf("%c ", init_char);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    int num;
    printf("input number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    nest_loop(num);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
input number: 5
A B C D E 
  A B C D 
    A B C 
      A B 
        A
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained by @Jonathon Reinhart, you only need two loops in a construct similar to:

```
for (int i = n; i > 0; i--) {
  for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
    [...]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You know in book also we write left to right not top to bottom so your understanding is wrong above about your loops. Feel free to ask any clarifications thank you.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
    void nest_loop(int n)
    {
        int i,j;
        char k = 'A';
        for(i=n;i>0;i--)
        {
            for(j=n;j>i;j--)
            {
                printf(" ");//print required spaces.
            }
            for(j=0;j<i;j++)
            {
                printf("%c",k+j);//initial char value of k is A and will be incremented by one as looping continues.
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    int main()
    {
        int n;
        printf("Enter the row number\n");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        nest_loop(n);
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you have functional code for your purpose

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    int num;
    scanf("%d", &num);
    char init_char = 'A';

    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++, init_char++){
        for(int j = num; j > i; j--)
            printf("%c", init_char);
        printf("\n");
    }

        return 0;
}
```

the answer is well explained in comments, good luck :)
*I'd add that in C language you can also increment chars, read what is ASCII table and how chars are encoded as numbers

Comment: Your code don’t produce the expected output. You get rows of A, B and C.

Comment: excuse me, this code works just fine on my machine, except of the output is aligned to the left. Does it really output only till the 'C' character on your machine?